# Unable to locate any i386 package

Tags: 13.10, package-management, dpkg

I've been messing with my system for a while to get it work after upgrade and now it kind of works, but is not healthy.

When I try to remove any i386 package on my 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 it returns an error:

```
root# apt-get remove zlib1g:i386   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package zlib1g
```

I know that it is installed from output of `dpkg -l`.

Comment: As I stated already my system is messed up and I'm getting a lot of warnings from dpkg when installing package. Similar to this: "dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsane:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed". But it really irritates me that apt-get doesn't find i386 packages.

Comment: Also, I can't install wine because depencies somehow reqiure wine1.x-i386, which seems to not exist for 64bit in wine repo.

Comment: wine depends on wine-i386 packages,so removing i386 packages will cause the software not to load.

Comment: I don't mind presence of i386 packages. But looks weird to me that apt doesn't find them.

Comment: check that your package name is correct o not?

Comment: Package name is correct. It isn't about one package, I've got lots of them, at least according to dpkg. But I'm not too sure about sanity of dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `zlib1g` is **already uninstalled** but it's **configration files still exist**.that is why apt-get is unable to find the package.
But when `dpkg -l` tries to find all installed packages,it searches for both packages as well as its configuration files.so it will still show `zlib1g` as installed.

So instead of running

> apt-get remove zlib1g:i386

(using `sudo` if not a root terminal)

run

> apt-get **purge** zlib1g:i386

(again using `sudo` if not a root terminal)

**purge** removes the configuration files as well as package.

Now when you run dpkg -l you will not find the package in the list.

The man page of `dpkg-query` gives some details.

> -l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
>                 List packages matching given pattern. If no package-name-pattern
>                 is  given,  list all packages in /var/lib/dpkg/status, excluding
>                 the ones marked as not-installed (i.e.  those  which  have  been
>                 previously  purged).

Comment: Why would it not work in a root terminal?

Comment: @Alaa because it would search in incorrect directories and root terminal is not the safe method to do this.`sudo` has been created for the very purpose of security from the possible danger of damaging the system by use of root terminal.never use root terminal unless it is necessary.

Comment: The second part of your comment is understandable, but what incorrect directories? `apt-get`'s "directories" are the same for everyone. I think what you're trying to get at is the `PATH` variable, but that won't affect `apt-get` in this case.

Comment: Alaa is right, doesn't work with sudo either.
How do I ensure that is present? It doesn't find any package:i386 I tried.

Comment: -search for zlib1g in ubuntu software center  


That will remove amd64 version, right?

Comment: Yes, it simply removes amd64 version. Tried it on different package though, too many reverse depensies for zlib1g.